# RxJS: Wait for one value, then dispose observer

Tags: rxjs

I'm not really sure how to ask this question, but I have code similar to this in my application, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle it.

```js
const d = this.$q.defer();
const s = this.change$  // <- A regular Subject, that emits whenever changes to the model arrive
    .subscribe(() => {
        d.resolve(this.promiseWereWaitingFor);
        s.unsubscribe();
    });

return d.promise;
```

I've tried using `takeLast` and that sort of stuff, but I don't want the stream to complete because it's reacting to user input (a search field, for example). And from what I understand, `.toPromise()` only resolves when the stream completes.

Is it possible to simplify my code, to avoid subscribing and unsubscribing all the time? And more importantly, is my code even bad practice?

Comment: Who is consuming `d`, and how?

Comment: If I understood it well you could try taking the first item of `change$` with `first` operator, `flatMap` it to `d` and subscribe

Comment: it is bad practice. Try: `return this.changes$.take(1).mapTo(this.promiseWereWaitingFor).toPromise()`

Comment: @torazaburo multiple methods are - this specific code example is used to make sure data is ready before moving on in multiple other methods. Specifically for this case, `this.promiseWereWaitingFor` must be resolved when the user has pressed enter, before moving on, but it's also returned to an external component that uses the resolved data for a list of search suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to complete when the first value has arrived after you start listening to it:

```
this.change$.take(1)
  .mapTo(this.promiseWereWaitingFor)
  .toPr‌​omise();
```

This will fulfil your promise when one value has arrived. Depending on your requirements this might be an issue; the promise *will not resolve until that value has arrived*. To safeguard for this you can add a Timeout:

```
this.change$.take(1)
  .mapTo(this.promiseWereWaitingFor)
  .timeout(2 * 1000) /* 2 seconds for promise to fulfil */
  .toPr‌​omise();
```

That way the promise is automatically rejected after 2 seconds if no value has been propagated.

Comment: Thing is, as mentioned in the question, I don't want to complete the stream whenever I need to react on it. If I did, I'd have to create a new stream all the time. Using `take(1)` will just return immediately because there's almost always data in the stream when this code is run

Comment: When using a _vanilla_ [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) then `take(1)` will wait for the next value emission. If you do not want to complete then you should not use promises but try to stay Rx to do something based on emissions of your stream.

Answer (score 0):

In order to consume a series of promises derived from an observable, I am going to assume that your logic is something like the following:

```
// Handle a series of promises.
function handleSeries() {
  return getNewPromise().then(handleValue).then(handleSeries);
}
```

Where (using native promises), `getNewPromise` is implemented as follows:

```
let promise, resolveFunc, rejectFunc;

function getNewPromise() { return promise; }

function makeNewPromise() {
   promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolveFunc = resolve;
     rejectFunc = reject;
   });
}

makeNewPromise();

this.changes$.subscribe(
  change => { resolveFunc(change); makeNewPromise(); },
  error => { rejectFunc(error); makeNewPromise(); }
);
```

In other words, we define a promise named `promise`, then subscribe to the observable, and on each emission, resolve or reject that promise, and then create a new promise which the consumer can obtain with `getNewPromise` when he has finished with handling the previous promise.

This logic is not perfect, since it will skip some promises if the observable emits faster than `handleValue` can handle them. To solve this problem would require somehow queueing promises. But you get the idea.

But all you have accomplished here, really, is to transform a perfectly good observable into a series of promises returned by repeated calls to `getNewPromise`. But an observable is already a series of things, which `subscribe` allows you to get one at a time. Therefore, the entire code above is almost exactly equivalent to just saying

```
this.changes$.subscribe(handleValue)
```

with the added advantage that errors and completion is handled automatically.

With your approach, you are mixing two different paradigms--observables and promises--in a way which is likely to confuse you and anyone reading your code. But they are designed to do different things: a promise represents a one-time future value, whereas an observable represents a stream of future values. You seem to be trying to use promises to represent individual emissions on the observable. But emissions on an observable are already represented--by the observable itself. `toPromise` is designed to bridge this gap in the case where it is meaningful due to the fact that the observable is intended to emit only a single value, or perhaps an error right away.

Therefore, if I understand your situation correctly, you should skip using promises, and have your consumer(s) use the observable as intended, by just subscribing to it directly.